# Cannot retrieve renamed file paths from external storage

Tags: android

I am reading the paths of the files using a Cursor to access content://media/external/file/
The problem is that when I rename a file I get the path with the old name unless I also modify the content of the file. In this case it returns the path with the renamed name.

```
 Uri uri =  MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
 Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, orderBy);
```

Could anybody tell me if it's possible to retrieve the correct paths(after renaming)?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. And you do all without code! And without questions.

Comment: "I am reading the paths of the files using a Cursor" -- assuming that you are referring to the `DATA` column, you needed to stop doing that months ago, as that is not available to you on Android 10 and higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. Yes I am using DATA and I noticed it's deprecated even though it's still working at the moment. What would you suggest to retrieve all the files paths? Would you suggest to discard the Cursor approach and scan recursively the filesystem using File()?

Comment: "What would you suggest to retrieve all the files paths?" -- that is not possible in general, as Google continues to tighten Android security. On Android 10, it is flat-out impossible. On Android R, there is a `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission that might give you some options. However, it is poorly documented and, AFAICT, does not actually work in the first developer preview. And, the Play Store is going to demand a reason why you request that permission, and unless you have a very good one, you will not be able to distribute your app there.